# Need to add 0 to match the length

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have unique identifiers for each row. For example `19Jan187938` or `19Jan206414` but there are some which are like `19Jan17333`. I need to add a `0` before the number if it's 5 digits, so it becomes `19Jan017333`.

I tried,

```
=TEXT(CONCATENATE(19,AB2,C2),"000000")
```

even with 11 `0`'s, since the total length is 11. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(AB2,5),TEXT(RIGHT(AB2,LEN(AB2)-5),"000000"))
```

It will basically, take the first 5 characters and concatenate that with the remaining characters formatted as a six digit number with leading zeroes

Comment: Ah I see the goal now! :) +

Answer (score 0):

If your identifier is on A1, you can try this:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)<11;CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;5);RIGHT("000000"&MID(A1;6;5);6));A1)
```

See what happens.